# Query URL with GraphQL return "Syntax Error GraphQL (1:35) Expected Name"

Tags: javascript, json, api, url, graphql

I try to add query in a link using API `GraphQL`:

```
 https://app.io/graphql?query={getUserLandfields(userId:b98a07c7-14d5-48fe-841a-d8726b75f528,page:1,items:1){count,landfields{id,forSale,thumbnail,description,location,center,price,purchaseValue,country,tileCount,currentValue,tradingValue}}}
```

but return this error **Syntax Error GraphQL (1:35) Expected Name**.

Someone can explain me this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Syntax Error GraphQL (1:35) Expected Name.` is telling you that line 1 column 35 in your query has an issue. If you look at the query

> {getUserLandfields(userId:b98a07c7-14d5-48fe-841a-d8726b75f528,page:1,items:1)

column 35 is around `-14d5`.

Your error is because your query is invalid, it is not related to the fact that you're using it in a URL parameter.

```
getUserLandfields(userId:b98a07c7-14d5-48fe-841a-d8726b75f528,
```

needs to have quotes around the UUID, e.g.

```
getUserLandfields(userId:"b98a07c7-14d5-48fe-841a-d8726b75f528",
```

otherwise `userId:b98a07c7-14d5` is basically going to be tokenized roughly along the lines of

```
userId:b98a07c7 -14 d5
```

where `b98a07c7` is just a named value for `userId` (which isn't a valid UUID, but it's not validated until later), and then the rest of the tokens will be parsed as if they are more arguments for `getUserLandfields`, so the parser is looking for a "Name" for the next argument, hence the "Expected Name." error message. Given what you've provided, it sees that `-14` is a number instead, not a `Name`, so it errors.

Comment: my friend i love you ! amazing :)